# Compare columns & count only unique values under a parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm looking to do the following in excel with a formula that could update itself as the table of data grows.

I have a column with Territory codes like "3-1", "3-2", etc and there's another column with the name of the company.  Only problem is they duplicate & I can't delete the duplicates.  So for example if there is 3-1 - Acme Co., 3-1 - Acme Co., 3-1 Acme Inc., I'd want the formula to show me that Territory 3-1 has 2 accounts.

I hope this makes sense & is possible.

Very much appreciate the help!

Comment: like [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)?

Comment: CountIF won't work on it's own because of the duplicates. In my example you see that if I used a simple CountIF it would tell me there were 3 accounts in that territory rather than the correct 2 accounts.

Comment: okay then, [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) with an s.  This allows multiple criteria.

Comment: I don't need to it look for multiple criteria.  I need it to count a single criteria but ignore duplicates.  I'll try another example. Column A has 1, 1, 2 and Column B has A, A, B respectively.  I want a formula that will tell me that account 1 has 1 customer (A) & account 2 has 1 customer (B), customer A just happens to appear on multiple rows.  Sorry if this is too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper column:

[image]

In that column put the following in C2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)
```

And copy down.

Then either use a pivot table to get the sum of the helper column, or:

[image]

use SumIfs:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,E2)
```

Comment: @AnthonyOlivieri  Try this out, but wait till Dirk responds, he may yet find a way to do it in one formula, I couldn't.

Comment: @AnthonyOlivieri I appreciate the consideration, but Dirk's latest formula does it without the helper column, and is what I would use if I was in your place.

Comment: It's like "BAM! solved without excel"... I didn't mind the points :P

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20=A1)/COUNTIFS(A1:A20,A1:A20,B1:B20,B1:B20,...))
```

Or as dragable:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$20=$A1)/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$20,$A$1:$A$20,$B$1:$B$20,$B$1:$B$20,...))
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk but won't this only count the unique values in a single column? That's not what I need here.

Comment: I'm not that fast only using the phone :P

Comment: Haha no worries Dirk! I think we're getting warmer but still not quite there. I think I'm explaining it poorly.  I don't need to count ALL unique values. I only need the unique count based on a parameter.

Comment: The best example I could give was above where one column has repeating company names & another has those company territory numbers but the numbers & the accounts duplicate down the rows.  Territory A may have 10 companies but in the sheet it's 40 lines of those 10 duplicating.

Comment: Just a moment pls... still only at the phone... need to use my brain... no office here...

Comment: Do a filter on territory?